# Are there dangers in inference when collecting additional samples in descriptive research?

Tags: sampling, descriptive-statistics, statistical-power

I recognize that, for hypothesis testing, collecting additional samples after the fact present additional researcher degrees of freedom, and break several of the key assumptions we have in interpreting our results.

In descriptive research, however, are there similar concerns about our ability to collect additional data?

I am interested in collecting data using an experimental design that varies continuously across two different variables.  My intuition is poor regarding how these variables work and whether results may vary due to a specific (mildly complex) interaction of the variables.  If I have an intuition regarding what I would like my confidence bands to be, would it be inappropriate to collect data until my estimates produce a specific confidence band?

**EDIT:** Title revised based on comment -- I meant descriptive research rather than descriptive statistics.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd be calculating confidence intervals - that's inferential rather than descriptive statistics.

Comment: @Scortchi Sorry about that, I meant descriptive research rather than descriptive statistics.  I'm interested in estimating population values, so the confidence bands should provide an estimate of uncertainty in those estimates.  I am not, however, looking to test hypotheses (i.e., is _a_ different from _b_ or different from _0_).  Visually, I'm aiming for something like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Binomial_confidence_band.svg/720px-Binomial_confidence_band.svg.png).